# My stream writer creates the file but doesn't insert the data?

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

This is the code for creating a stream writer and feeding some data into the sample.dat file.
but the code just creates the file but doesn't insert the data.

```
write = new StreamWriter("sample.dat");

using (write)
{
    write.WriteLine("11111,Adam Bakerr,825.50");
    write.WriteLine("22222,Sophie Ali,1000000");
    write.WriteLine("33333,Ian Rich,3");
    write.WriteLine("44444,Guy Poor,123456789");
    write.WriteLine("55555,Bob Sponge,515");
    write.WriteLine("66666,Marie Currie,88");
    write.Flush();
}
write.Close();
```

Also, I want to insert the data if the file is created for the first time only, please
and I want to update a specific record if a file is already created with those data.

Comment: The code you've shown works fine (assuming `write` is declared somewhere) so you've misdiagnosed the source of the problem. Maybe you've got other code that runs after that empties the file. Maybe the file being written to isn't in the location you assume, etc.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], as the code provided, given the right type for `write`, works just fine. Since you're not specifying the full path to the file, could it be that your code produces a text file somewhere unexpected, and what you're looking at is an older/wrong copy of the file, which is empty?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes the 'write' is declared at the beginning of my code

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I will try that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code in a test app worked fine for me:

```
    if(!File.Exists(@"c:\ab\simple.dat")) // Only run if the file doesn't exist
    {
        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"c:\ab\simple.dat"))
        {
            write.WriteLine("11111,Adam Bakerr,825.50");
            write.WriteLine("22222,Sophie Ali,1000000");
            write.WriteLine("33333,Ian Rich,3");
            write.WriteLine("44444,Guy Poor,123456789");
            write.WriteLine("55555,Bob Sponge,515");
            write.WriteLine("66666,Marie Currie,88");
        }
    }
```

If you want to change a specific line, you'd have to read the contents of your file into a string array, change the relevant line and then re-write your file.

Comment: Does it create the ab folder if it doesn't exist already or shall I create it myself?

Comment: No you'll need the folder path to exist. It will create the file if it doesn't exist and write the contents into the file. It won't do anything if the file already exists.

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\File' is denied.'
this is the error that shows when I try to create file anywhere. I only have C drive on my pc

Comment: Just make a folder in the C: drive. Chances are you can't write to the root of the OS disk unless you're running as Administrator.

Comment: How do i run as an administrator? I only have one user account in my pc

Comment: Right-click and choose "Run as Administrator" from the context menu.

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException <br> again same exception. Do you want more detail about my problem? Please let me know with a specific detailed description.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you don't have rights to create a file in the location you've specified. You can just change the path in my test code to somewhere you do have permission to create files.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the answer. That was really helpful